# Dynamically accessing function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi have the following simple ExpressJS application, where the routes are dynamically created based on a configuration. I am having a hard time trying to pass in a bunch of parameters to the handler so that the values are returned in the respective controller.

```js
const express = require('express');

module.exports = class App {
  get routes() {
    return [
      {
        path: '/',
        verb: 'get',
        method: 'home',
        params: ['req.query.ref', 'req.query.country'],
      },
    ];
  }

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.register();
  }

  register() {
    const { routes } = this;
    routes.forEach((route) => {
      const {
        path, verb, method, params,
      } = route;
      // if you replace the params with [req.query.ref, req.query.country] it will work as expected
      this.app[verb](path, this.handler(this[method].bind(this), (req, res, next) => params));
    });
  }

  handler(promise, params) {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
      const bound = params ? params(req, res, next) : [];

      console.log(bound);

      try {
        const result = await promise(...bound);
        res.json(result);
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };
  }

  home(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    return Promise.resolve({ status: 'OK' });
  }
};
```

Comment: You should probably use `eval` while assigning bound, else it will evaluate to a string `req.query.ref`

Comment: Thanks, but isn't using `eval` dangerous?

Comment: Yes, but currently req.query.ref is stored as a string and you need to convert it to the real value

Comment: You could write a custom converter by splitting by '.' and recursively iterating the object

Comment: The converter is an interesting suggestion, could you elaborate?

Comment: It will work only on simple expressions, with only `.` 's. something like `_.reduce(path.split('.'), function (result, value) {
            return result ? result[value] : undefined;`

Comment: Nice, where would I place this?

Comment: Please figure that out :-)

Comment: @Malice What? Using eval here is downright bad advice. That's nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your issues stem from the structure of your route definition. It would make more sense to create direct references to the things you want to use, not noting function references etc down as strings.

```
get routes() {
    return [{
        path: '/',
        method: this.get,
        endpoint: this.home,
        paramMap: req => [req.query.ref, req.query.country],
    }];
}
```

Once you make the appropriate changes elsewhere, you no longer have the original problem you described.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you, and thanks for the restructure tip too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look to the arguments object. All functions have this object and it contains an array with all arguments received in the function. I think it could be what you are looking for.

JavaScript functions have a built-in object called the arguments object.

The argument object contains an array of the arguments used when the function was called (invoked).

This way you can simply use a function to find (for instance) the highest value in a list of numbers:

This is an example how it works:

```
x = findMax(1, 123, 500, 115, 44, 88);

function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

More info: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18398621)

Comment: More info added. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

well you can build the query if with split if your **params** has the same format

--update--

this solution is based on req or res with x params for each

```js
const express = require('express');

module.exports = class App {
  get routes() {
    return [
      {
        path: '/',
        verb: 'get',
        method: 'home',
        params: ['req.query.ref', 'req.query.country'], //changed
      },
    ];
  }

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.register();
  }

  register() {
    const { routes } = this;
    routes.forEach((route) => {
      let {
        path, verb, method, params,
      } = route;
      
      this.app[verb](path, this.handler(this[method].bind(this), (req, res, next) => this. paramsStringToArrayValues(req, res,params))
      }));
    });
  }
  
  paramsStringToArrayValues(req, res,params){
      return  params.map(param => {
                  let paramArr = param.split('.');
                  let obj  = paramArr.shift() === 'req'? req : res
                  paramArr.forEach(key =>{
                    obj = obj[key]
                  })
                  return obj
      })
  }

  handler(promise, params) {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
      const bound = params ? params(req, res, next) : [];

      console.log(bound);

      try {
        const result = await promise(...bound);
        res.json(result);
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };
  }

  home(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    return Promise.resolve({ status: 'OK' });
  }
};
```

Comment: That's great, one thing though.. the params array value could be anything from `req`, `res.headers` or `req.query.name`.